# Which is the lesser of two evils? Markup in the ViewModel or logic in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, markup, wcag

I am working on a WCAG AA compliant site.  This means that input forms should have the following attributes if they are no null or empty:

```
required='required'
value='{the value}'
```

If they are null or empty then those attributes should not be present.  Hence the following will fail WCAG on two accounts.

```
<input type='date' required='false' value='' />
```

I started off with an if statement in the razor view:

```
@if (Model.HasValue) 
{
<input type="date" id="@Model.Name" name="@Model.Name" min="1990-01-01" max="2100-01-01" value="@Model.CoercedValue" />
}
else { 
<input type="date" id="@Model.Name" name="@Model.Name" min="1990-01-01" max="2100-01-01" />
}
```

but this starts to get ugly real fast when other optional attributes are added.  It becomes four statements when the required attribute is added.

---

I feel there are two ways to go on this, either push the logic to the ViewModel so it returns an attribute string:

```
public string this[string key]
{
    get { 
        switch (key){
            case "Required":
                return IsRequired?"required='required'":String.Empty;
            case "Value": 
                return HasValue ? String.Format("value='{0}'", CoercedValue) : String.Empty;
            default: 
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

The View then looks like this:

```
<input type='date' @Model["Required"] @Model["Value"] />
```

---

The alternate is to put this logic in a code block in the View

```
@{
   RequiredAttr = IsRequired?"required='required'":String.Empty;
   ValueAttr = HasValue ? String.Format("value='{0}'", CoercedValue) : String.Empty;
}
```

and the rest of the view markup:

```
<input type='date' @RequiredAttr @ValueAttr />
```

---

I am leaning to the markup in the ViewModel, but is that the best place for it?  Am I missing a pattern that would solve this?

Comment: I think writing an extension to `Html` would be a good solution.

Comment: Have you tried using helper functions ? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Comment: Why not just use the standard TextboxFor helper and add these other items as attributes when necessary?

Comment: @Matthew - Yes I had considered that, I have half a dozen distinct input types that all derive from the same base abstractions (IInputViewModel & InputViewModel).  I guess one of the reasons I am leaning to the first option is simplicity, I can simply write that logic once in the abstraction and be done.  Simplicity is not always the best practice.

Comment: @JoelEtherton - the required attribute is determined at runtime from a backend report engine.  The value is only populated on repost for validation errors but would otherwise be blank.

Comment: @Kami - with all deference to Scott Gutherie, I see cshtml + code as a bad thing.

Comment: @Blah_Blah, helper functions are nearly the opposite of "cshtml + code", so not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @KirkWoll - yes helper functions as per Matthew suggests are, the example on the ScottGu blog are not.  He clearly has logic in his cshtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal take is that "no code in the View" is a strong guideline, but not absolute gospel.  I have used code in my Views on occasions where the logic is

1. Simple
2. Intended to affect *only* the HTML in the View, not directly affecting the state of the model.

I think Matthew's comment that an extension to make a custom WCAG-compliant input field would work well.  It's repeatable, consistent, and encapsulates the concern cleanly.

Comment: You really do not use `@foreach (var row in Model.Rows) { <tr>...</tr> }`?  (Perhaps you meant "no logic in the View"?)

Comment: I expect that custom extensions are the way to go, and when I get some open time on this project I will move in this direction.  The lesser evil is to put the markup in the Controller until that time.